# Присвойте переменной x значение строки txt, только без пробелов в начале и конце

Tags: python

txt = “Hello World”

Если я правильно поняла задание, то задачи решение выглядит так:
txt = “ Hello World “
Но код не работает

Comment: Наоборот же вроде вам нужно убрать пробелы в начале и конце (если они есть). Для этого даже специальная функция есть в питоне.

Comment: `txt = " Hello World ".strip()`

Comment: Тогда жду помощи, а точнее какую команду использовать

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вам нужно что-то такое

```
txt = " Hello World! "
x = txt.strip()
print("+" + x + "+") #плюсики чтобы убедиться что пробелов в начале и в концем больше нет
```

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ отметьте его как правильный, пожалуйста